# Can this router and motherboard connect via the LAN 10G Port?

Tags: networking, local-area-network, 10gbethernet

So I am a bit confused :)

I have this unit, which advertises a "10G Lan SFP+" port

http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/R9000/R9000_UM_EN.pdf

And I am thinking of buying this motherboard

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketTRX4/ROG_ZENITH_II_EXTREME/E16262_ROG_ZENITH_II_EXTREME_UM_V2_WEB.pdf

Which advertises an Aquantia AGC-107 10g

And then I have some ethernet cable I've used for years (not sure what type)

Are the router and motherboard's 10G LAN compatible? (one says SFP+ and one doesn't)

Do I need a new or specific cable to connect the units?

If SFP+ is not included in 10g LAN, is it the assumed the same as if SFP+ LAN?

Thank you :)

Comment: for what does you nees fps 10g is 10g,but if you need specific features then look for thesame cards

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the SFP+ port in that router you will also require a 10GBase-T transceiver module. It does not appear to come with the transceiver included. To make use of these interfaces you will also need a CAT6 or CAT6A cable (decide depending on the performance requirements and distance of the run).

You should be fine with a CAT6 cable unless you are really pushing the distance or expecting full 10G speeds.

```
CAT6A 10GBASE-T up to 100m 
CAT6  10GBASE-T up to  55m
```

Looking at [NetGear's site](https://kb.netgear.com/31408/What-SFP-modules-are-compatible-with-my-Nighthawk-X10-R9000-router) they report that only fiber optic transceivers are usable with 10G speeds:

```
The following SFP+ modules are compatible with your R9000, R8900 and XR700 routers:

10GBase-SR SFP+ module
    Avago. AFBR-703SDZ
    Cisco. SFP-10G-SR
    Finisar. FTLX8571D3BCV (1G/10G)
    Sumitomo. SPP5101SR-GL
    NETEGAR. AXM761
10GBase-LR SFP+ module
    Avago. AFCT-7010SDZ
    Cisco. SFP-10G-LR
    Finisar. FTLX1471D3BCL
    Sumitomo. SPP5101LR-GL
10GBase-LRM SFP+ module
    Avago. AFBR-707SDZ
    Cisco. SFP-10G-LRM
```

However there is a [NetGear community thread](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Nighthawk-WiFi-Routers/AXM765-to-convert-the-SFP-port-to-a-10G-ethernet/td-p/1454303) where one user reports having used a MikroTik S+RJ10 (a 10GBase-T SFP+ transceiver).

[image: S+RJ10 (a 10GBase-T SFP+ transceiver)]

This is definitely possible, I have experienced third party transceivers working in enterprise level networking devices. With that being said, try it at your own risk, maybe examine return policies or other options before proceeding.

If this MikroTik SFP+ transceiver works in the router, and you connect with a CAT6 or CAT6A, you will be good to go for 10G connectivity between the router and your device.

Comment: The SFP+ you may be looking for is NETGEAR AXM765 (with RJ45 interface). Mikrotik S+RJ10 ( https://mikrotik.com/product/s_rj10 ) may be one option or you can use e.g. FibreStore alternative - AXM765 ( https://www.fs.com/de-en/products/76126.html ). In principle it will do the same...